# Specflow defination not showing references

Tags: .net, automation, integration-testing, bdd, specflow

I have a spec flow automation framework. I am using Visual Studio Editor. in that, any definition in the definition file shows references zero. I want to display the reference number with the definition.

suggest to me the solution to display the references with definitions.

As in the image the reference shows zero even if it referred at a number of places in the project:
[image: code image]

I did research and installed some extensions of Spec-flow but it did not work. also, I follow the spec flow documentation